# How to unlist a nested named list without including prefix in R?

Tags: r

I have the following piece of code:

```
#example
test <- list("a" = 1, "b" = 2)
test2 <- list("x.y.z" = test)

unlist(test2["x.y.z"])
```

This resulting named vector is the following:

```
x.y.z.a     x.y.z.b 
1           2
```

However, I would like the result to **not** include the prefix of the nested list. It should be a named vector, but I don't want to include the information of how it was nested. **The result I'm looking for:**

```
a   b 
1   2
```

I understand that I can probably loop through each item and replace everything except the last character, but I think there should be a more efficient way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[`

```
unlist(test2[["x.y.z"]])

#a b 
#1 2
```

Or `$`

```
unlist(test2$x.y.z)
```